pkcs11interop session pops up the wrong "Token logon" window , instead of "Digital Signature PIN logon" window (thales/Gemalto vendor eTPKCS11.dll)
I am using the pkcs11interop to create the session for a token
and force the "Digital Signature PIN logon" popup to appear for user.
but wrong popup shows "Token logon":

but this should be shown:

so is there any way to show the right PIN logon popup?
the used code is:
string exePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string pkcs11LibraryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(exePath, @"eTPKCS11.dll");//I can access also IDPrimePKCS11.dll

Pkcs11InteropFactories factories = new Pkcs11InteropFactories();
try
{
    using (IPkcs11Library pkcs11Library = factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(factories, pkcs11LibraryPath, AppType.MultiThreaded))
    {
        ILibraryInfo libraryInfo = pkcs11Library.GetInfo();
               
        // Get list of all available slots
        foreach (ISlot slot in pkcs11Library.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithOrWithoutTokenPresent))
        {
            ISlotInfo slotInfo = slot.GetSlotInfo();

            if (slotInfo.SlotFlags.TokenPresent)
            {
                ITokenInfo tokenInfo = slot.GetTokenInfo();
                using (ISession session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadWrite))
                {
                    // Attempt to login to the session
                    // Pass null or empty string to trigger the PIN dialog
                    session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, (string)null);
                                     
                    //PDF SIGNING HERE
                    DoSigningAndUpload();
                               
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Thanks in advance
vendor dll-s which check for used slots eTPKCS11.dll ,IDPrimePKCS11.dll and eventualy can show the right popup

AFAIK the second dialog is appearing on CKU_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC login user type after successfully login on first time with CKU_USER without logging out.

Please also check the difference between labels against PIN code field: Token Password vs Digital Signature PIN.

I suggest that your token have CKF_SECONDARY_AUTHENTICATION flag set - this can explain the second authentication dialog.
